# Bitbucket Pipeline - Applications not found

Tags: java, spring-boot, cicd, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a Bitbucket pipeline with the aim to deploy a built jar file to a Spring Boot server.

The first step to maven build the jar file completes successfully, however the second step that copies the jar to an S3 bucket fails with an error.

**Error**

```
✖ Failed to register application revision.
An error occurred (ApplicationDoesNotExistException) when calling the RegisterApplicationRevision operation: Applications not found for 602169630266
```

I am guessing that it is related to this entry in the *bitbucket-pipelines.yml*:

```
APPLICATION_NAME: 'pow-wow'
```

**bitbucket-pipelines.yml**

```
image: maven:3.9.0
pipelines:
  custom:
    upload-and-deploy-to-uat:
        - step:
            name: Build
            caches:
              - maven
            script:
              - echo 'Maven Build'
              - mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip
              - echo "$(date +%Y-%m-%d) $BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER $BITBUCKET_COMMIT"
            artifacts:
              - target/pow-wow-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar
              - appspec.yml
        - step:
            name: Upload to UAT S3
            script:
              - echo "Upload to AWS S3 Bucket on UAT ($UAT_AWS_DEFAULT_REGION) $(date +%Y-%m-%d) (powwow-$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER-$BITBUCKET_COMMIT)"
              - pipe: atlassian/aws-code-deploy:1.2.0
                variables:
                  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $UAT_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
                  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $UAT_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
                  AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $UAT_AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
                  COMMAND: 'upload'
                  ZIP_FILE: 'target/pow-wow-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar'
                  APPLICATION_NAME: 'pow-wow'
                  S3_BUCKET: ${UAT_S3_BUCKET}
                  VERSION_LABEL: "powwow-${BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER}-${BITBUCKET_COMMIT}"
                  DEBUG: 'true'
        - step:
            name: Deploy to the UAT Server
            script:
              - echo "Deploy with AWS CodeDeploy to UAT ($UAT_AWS_DEFAULT_REGION) Application Server $(date +%Y-%m-%d) (powwow-$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER-$BITBUCKET_COMMIT)"
              - pipe: atlassian/aws-code-deploy:1.2.0
                variables:
                  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $UAT_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
                  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $UAT_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
                  AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $UAT_AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
                  COMMAND: 'deploy'
                  APPLICATION_NAME: 'pow-wow'
                  DEPLOYMENT_GROUP: 'deployment-group'
                  IGNORE_APPLICATION_STOP_FAILURES: 'true'
                  FILE_EXISTS_BEHAVIOR: 'OVERWRITE'
                  WAIT: 'true'
                  S3_BUCKET: ${UAT_S3_BUCKET}
                  VERSION_LABEL: 'powwow-${BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER}-${BITBUCKET_COMMIT}'
                  DEBUG: 'true'
```

**appspec.yml**

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: target/pow-wow-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar
    destination: /home/jboss/bitbucket/pow-wow
hooks:
  BeforeInstall:
    - location: scripts/powwow-deploy.sh
```

Here is the deployment script, but i do't think it is reaching this point yet:

**powwow-deploy.sh**

```
#clear
echo "about to deploy to pow-wow ..."
#cd pow-wow
echo $JAVA_HOME
echo | java -version
echo PATH: $PATH
echo "stop pow-wow ..."
if [ -e target/pid.file ]
then
    kill $(cat target/pid.file)
    echo "Killed PID: "+cat target/pid.file" (server stopped)."
else
    echo "target/pid.file not found, so server probably not running or has not been started with this script yet."
fi
echo "start pow-wow ..."
cat nohup.out >> nohup-$(date --iso).out
rm nohup.out
nohup java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=uat target/pow-wow-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar &
echo $! > target/pid.file
echo "Started pow-wow on PID: "+cat target/pid.file" (server started). Logs can be found here: ~/bitbucket/pow-wow/nohup.out"
```